# Collision Detection in Box2d (cocos2d )

Tags: ios4, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have made 10 different static body placed along straight path. I want to detect Collision of a moving body with these  different static body. How can i detect the collision of specific object(without using TileMap)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial is very helpful for  Collision detection:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone